# Can't ping IPv6 server on internet from Debian running on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, debian, ipv6, airport

I cannot `ping6` out from my Debian machine (Jessie) running in VirtualBox using `ping6 ipv6.google.com` command. I am, however, able to ping IPv6 addresses on my LAN with `ping6`.

My ISP has IPv6 and my WAN IP address is IPv6.

I have an Apple Airport router which I just upgraded the firmware on. Router mode is `"DHCP and NAT."` Its `"Configure IPv6"` is set to `"Automatically."` Its `"IPv6 Mode"` is set to `"Native."` The `"Enable IPv6 Connection Sharing"` setting is ticked (on).

On VirtualBox, the network adapter is enabled and `"Attached to"` a `"Bridged Adapter."` The `"Name"` is `"en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)."`

This issue is causing problems for me because I cannot `apt-get update` anything from Debian's security server at `http://security.debian.org/` which uses an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

There was a "Block incoming IPv6" connections setting on the Airport router. Turning this off fixed the problem. It's under "Network" -> "Network Options" in the Airport router utility.